# Embed image from GitHub private repo

Tags: github

I have a private repo in GitHub where I'm saving some screenshots.

`https://github.com/erikmartinjordan/Screenshots`

To embed a picture of this repo into an **external markdown file**, I copy the full image address (right-click on the picture):

`![Private picture](https://github.com/erikmartinjordan/Screenshots/blob/master/Screenshot.png?raw=true)`

The problem is that the picture doesn't display in the browser (only when I'm logged in GitHub). Is there a simple way to display pictures of external GitHub private repos without using the GitHub API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display your image from the repo, you can use `raw.githubusercontent.com`.

So for [this](https://github.com/erikmartinjordan/Screenshots/blob/master/Screenshot%202020-09-15%20at%2010.32.38.png) image from your repo, you need to use the markdown as

```
![Private picture](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erikmartinjordan/Screenshots/master/Screenshot%202020-09-15%20at%2010.32.38.png)
```

Using the same markdown here:

[image: Private picture]

In case the image is part of a **private GitHub repo**, accessing that outside GitHub is not possible without **using an access token** generated by you (can be generated at https://github.com/settings/tokens when you are logged in). You need to then use the token as

```
![Private picture](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erikmartinjordan/Screenshots/master/Screenshot%202020-09-15%20at%2010.32.38.png?token=xxxxxxxx)
```

**But ensure that you don't expose the token in public**