# Image not getting embedded to github.io webpage despite getting embedded properly in github readme.md file[Edit : Solved]

Tags: github, github-pages

The image is getting embedded in readme file , but in the webpage , it is broken! what shall be the problem?

PS: stack is not allowing me to post any images, i embed the images using the standrard markup command !["description"]("https://....

Comment: Can you try if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63915756/embed-image-from-github-private-repo/63924918#63924918) of mine helps?

Comment: Hi @MadhuBhat, thank you for your answer! , but i solved my problem by using relative links instead of absolute links to embed the images! , but i went through your answer and i also think raw.github.com would do good if i wanna include absolute links ! , mine was a painful one as i had to move all my images to my home github repo!